# Syntax for db columns with comma separated lists - mySQL `IN` operator

Tags: mysql, arrays, subquery, in-operator

When using an `IN` operator in a `SELECT`statement, what is the proper syntax to use for db column names in a `subquery` when they contain comma separated lists (in either or both columns)?

In the snippet below I'm trying to identify the products available in the customer's preferred colors (there can be one or more values in either column)

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.Colors IN (SELECT style.colors_love FROM style WHERE user_id = $user_id)
```

This format works with a hard-coded list:

```
$colors_love = "'Black','Royal_Blue','Dodger_Blue','Red'";
SELECT * FROM products WHERE products.Color IN ('$colors_love')
```

I've tried everything I could think, including declaring it as an `array` and trying to concatenate the values, and since my coding is a bit rusty I have a feeling that my syntax is just slightly off.

Comment: Your first select seems to be the right idea, but it references `customers.Colors_Prefer` but doesn't include the `customers` table. What does it mean to pull `customers.Colors_Prefer` from the `style` table?

Comment: @lurker -  My bad - that was a typo I made when cleaning up the snippet to post the question :-( Thanks for catching that ;-)

Comment: Is the first `SELECT` failing in some way? If so, what's the error?

Comment: @lurker - It is ;-) To further complicate matters it's not giving me an error code even though error reporting is on and it does get through to the bottom of the page properly (since it echos everything else on the page)

Comment: @Strawberry - I was under the impression that 'join' is only used for tables which are connected in some way (i.e. to connect tables with foreign keys). Is it also used for tables where the data isn't connected?

Comment: @ChayaCooper that is correct. You are, on the other hand, obtaining data from an independent table if I read your problem correctly. With your current `SELECT`, if you aren't getting an error, are you getting any results or none? I'm not sure I know what you mean by, *it does get through to the bottom of the page properly*.

Comment: @lurker, My apologies if I wasn't being clear - I'm not getting any results (when I should get at least 7 rows) :-( I just meant that it's not getting stuck anywhere and is able to progress through the rest of the code.

Comment: The `SELECT` syntax with a subquery in the `IN` should work. Did you verify that `SELECT customers.Colors_Prefer FROM customers WHERE user_id = $user_id` gives you what you expect?

Comment: @lurker - I just confirmed that it does :-) If the query is simply ("SELECT customers.Colors_Prefer FROM customers WHERE user_id = $user_id"), then the result is: Black,Charcoal,Light_Gray,White,Royal_Blue,Dodger_Blue,Red

Comment: Well I tried the syntax you're using on a little test case, and it appears that it should work. I'm a little baffled why yours isn't working as desired. It might be something in the broader context. Is this all inside of a PHP program or something?

Comment: It's good to know it's not just me that's a little baffled by this :-) Yes, I'm doing it in PHP, but I'm not using a framework

Comment: What I'm getting at here is whether there's something else in the context preventing you from seeing the proper results, especially in light of the fact that it's not generating an error. I might suggest connecting directly to the database with a `mysql` command line and try the query there if you haven't already to see if it yields proper results.

Comment: @lurker - I just tested it in phpMyAdmin and I'm still running into the same problem :-( It works fine when the column in the subquery has only 1 value, but it returns an empty result set (i.e. zero rows) if it contains a comma-separated list.

Comment: If a single customer row can have multiple preferred colors in a comma separated list, then this mechanism won't work at all. As @Strawberry indicated, you need to normalize the data. One thing you can do is create a `preferred_color` table which has a color and customer_id for each row to reflect a *customer has many preferred colors* relationship. Then restructure the query to join with the preferred colors.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT p.* 
  FROM products p
  JOIN customers c 
    ON c.Colors_Prefer = p.colors 
 WHERE c.user_id = $user_id;
```

If we consider the example of preferred colours, a normalized approach might look like this:

```
user preferred_colour 
bob  red
bob  yellow
mike red
mike green
dave turquoise
```

If you want to store hundreds of attributes in this fashion, then an EAV approach may be suitable:

```
user attribute value
bob  colour    red
bob  colour    yellow
mike colour    red
mike colour    green
dave colour    turquoise
dave vehicle   bicycle
dave vehicle   car
bob  vehicle   train
```

But if doing it this way, I'd still be tempted to create different tables for each different data type - so, at a minimu, a table for numeric type attributes and a table for string type attributes.

Comment: I was under the impression that 'join' is only used for tables which are connected in some way (i.e. to connect tables with foreign keys). Is it also used for tables where the data isn't connected? In this example I'm trying to identify the products which are available in the customer's preferred colors

Comment: You're correct. The part I forgot to mention was the requirement to abandon the comma-separated list. Instead see normalization

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way that normalization and a lack of comma-separated lists intersect :-( However, in this particular instance I don't think it would make sense to get rid of the comma-separated lists because that would require separate columns for every possible value (i.e. instead of 1 column for the colors they like, you'd have to have 1 column for each of over 200 colors, and the same would be true of every single style attribute we're capturing). It would also require completely redoing a substantial portion of the website, so for the moment I have to use the db as is.

Comment: No. It would require separate rows for every single value - in a separate table. That's normalization.

Comment: Can you explain to me why that is important? Just to clarify, for each customer I am currently capturing information on apx. 400 attributes (i.e. Colors_Prefer), and most attributes have bet. 100-300 possible values (i.e. 200+ Colors). At present the attributes are split into several tables, and each customer is on a separate row (I use foreign keys to connect the customer's data to their id throughout).

Comment: There is absolutely no obligation on your part to use MySQL - or any other RDBMS. However, if you do want to use an RDBMS for storing data then normalization is fundamental to that process. Otherwise, the RBMS offers no advantage over any other storage method - a text file, say. BTW, it's highly unlikely that anyone would have 200 preferred colours. I doubt that that many people could even name 200 colours!

Comment: You're absolutely right about the # of preferred colors for a particular user :-) I was referring to the total list of possible values for each attribute (i.e. color, fabric type, etc.)

Comment: I'd never heard of EAV so I quickly looked it up (but obviously still don't know that much about it ;-)) Since I am storing hundreds of attributes for each user, am I right in understanding that it's ok to continue using comma-separated lists? Also, at the moment I've split the attributes into 3 tables, grouped by attribute categories (i.e. measurements, taste, lifestyle), so I'm curious if there would still be a benefit to splitting it by numeric vs. string type and if so how important that is.

Comment: If you want to search or compare those lists in SQL then no, it's not OK (although FIND_IN_SET() is blisteringly fast). If you just want to store the data for processing in some other application (some PHP, say), then it's fine. Efficient SQL (and I'm really talking about MySQL - but only because I'm unfamiliar with other dialects) depends on the appropriate use of indexes and data types. If you're not going to make use of the advantages that an RDBMS can provide then why bother with it? Text files are also great at storing data.

Comment: Take a look at wordpress. It uses EAV to some degree, but it tries to keep things orderly by making use of data types. Actually, it works very well!